# Tracking events in iOS with immediate results

Tags: ios, events, real-time, analytics, tracking

I have used analytic services such as flurry, parse, mixpanel etc. But I'm looking for a solution that would give me an immediate result from an in-app event. e.g. a button on the app is pressed and causes a website of mine to change background colour

Comment: Have you tried google analytics?

Comment: google analytics batches the request, so can be a few minutes out